# Sending serialized form as a parameter and adding more parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, serialization, parameters

I have a function called createLandOwner that should send a Ajax request with `"action=read"` and a serialized form as data. The serialized form is being provided as a parameter from event handlers on different forms.

How can I merge `"action=read"` and the serialized form as post data in the function createLandOwner?

My solution below results in "Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function" since data is a string, not an array.

**Event handler on a form**

```
$("#createLandOwnerForm").on( "submit", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

createLandOwner($(this).serialize(), appendCreatedLandOwnerToSelect, appendCreatedLandOwnerToSelect_Error);

});
```

**Function createLandOwner which sends the Ajax request**

```
function createLandOwner(landOwner, onSuccess, onError) {

var data = landOwner;

data.push({action: 'create'});

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: host + 'LandOwners.php',
    data: data,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`landOwner` is a uri encoded string...not an array.

You can simply add another param to end of that string

```
var data = landOwner + '&action=read';
```

Comment: Doh! I actually tried to concat the strings but I see that I forgot to put a '&' in the beggining. Thanks!